# How to handle exception while Re-Registering with Existing email and password in Firebase Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I made a **flutter app** and connected it with **Firebase authentication (using email and password)**. It's working perfectly. It creates a new user when a user register into app, signs out, and also signs in with that email and password.

But, when I try to **Re-Register with the same email and password** that I've used to create before OR when I try to **Sign in with an email which is not registered**, I get this *error*:

> PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_auth, com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":No address associated with hostname ], {}, null))

[image]

And the app just stops working, like in this case the loading is stopped: [See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmnC4.jpg)

This is the function to Register, SignIn function is similar to this:

```
Future registerWithEmailAndPasswordWithFirebase(
    String email, String password) async {
  try {
    UserCredential credential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    User user = credential.user;

    await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData('New user');

    return _returnUserUid(user);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above case, I ran the app using Vscode debugging. So, whenever it was getting an error, the app just stops there and vscode shows the PlatformException.

When I ran my app from terminal, then this issue didn't occur, it just shows that PlatformException in the terminal only and the app keep running.